# Where is Registered Server/Alias info physically stored?

Tags: sql-server

Running SQL Server 2012.

I tried importing a co worker registered server list (.regsrvr) file and it failed spectacularly. We think it is because of an incorrect password somewhere.

The problem now is that SSMS refuses to start and will not say why. I need to find out where Registered Server/Alias info is physically stored so I can remove it and get my SSMS booting up again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. For SQL Server 2012 on Windows 7/8, the offending file is located in

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Shell\RegSrvr.xml`

I got rid of it, and I got my SSMS running again!